# Creating a electronic circuit learning kit

Tags: electricity

I was thinking to create some electronic learning kit like this at home;

[image]

I need help to arrange ready to use or easily available items which can help me to make such kit to teach my 4 years old daughter electronic circuit as game.

For example: I can buy craft sticks. But since they are made from wood, I think I can break them while making holes. What I can use for joints like some dome nut? etc.

Comment: You do understand that craft sticks made of wood cannot be conductors. If you cannot make a hole in the end of a craft stick, you may not have the "tools" to accomplish your goal unaided. Rather than "reinvent the wheel" purchase any one of several kits (as you show in your image) already available. Consider, also, that four may be pushing things a bit. There's an average development tracker for your four y-o. http://www.pbs.org/parents/childdevelopmenttracker/four/index.html

Comment: I'm not sure if this is compatible with electronic components, but in general a sturdy cardboard box is a good base for a variety of homemade toys.  You can use a pencil or an awl to poke hole in a grid.  With age four, you'll want a widely spaced grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do It Yourself Electricity/Electronics Kit.

You can make a kit of components using an iron washer for each connector, pole, both ends of each wire lead, etc. and use a magnet at each junction for the connection.

Solder a small washer at the end of each component terminal and several wire leads.

To make a circuit, you would use a magnet as the base of each intended junction, and stack the washers "piggy-back" on top of each other for in-line, two-way, and three-way, etc. connections.

The washers conduct and the magnet can keep the washers securely connected with magnetism. Washers need not be large and are a "dime-a-dozen."

You will need all the components plus a bag of small iron washers, hook-up wire, and as many magnets as there are connections. Add magnets as your projects increase in complexity.

[image: connection detail of wire lead - top & side view]

You can "program" each of your projects by drawing the circuit diagram onto a sheet of cardboard with guidelines and symbols as to what goes where. Tape a magnet at each connection so they don't move around. What does the circuit do? Put the answer on the bottom of the card or under a flap for revealing the correct answer.

Comment: It's really helpful. And many thanks for the diagram so I can visualize it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your child's age. If she is beyond the stage of putting small objects in her mouth, you might use a [solderless "breadboard"](https://startingelectronics.org/beginners/start-electronics-now/tut1-breadboard-circuits/), such as that below.

[image: Electronic breadboard connector]

These allow use of any parts with small leads to be used (and reused).

However, you could use a [traditional *wooden* breadboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrG98HJ3Z6w) to make an educational kit. Permanently mount a few cells, a switch and some flashlight lamps to nails in a piece of wood, and your daughter can connect them with wires.

Comment: She is four (updated her age in question now). I was looking for the solution where she can build the circuit with minimal effort. Though your suggestion is really nice but I think breadboard may not be complex for her.

Comment: Oh man, do I love that traditional wooden breadboard breadboard. Thanx, Doc.